# Can i determine blend function per color attachment(drawbuffer) for frambuffer in WebGL2?

Tags: webgl, webgl2

I'm making a WebGL2 renderer with a Vulkan-like interface for private use.

In Vulkan, If I have multiple Color Attachment in a Framebuffer, I can choose BlendFunc per Color Attachment while creating a graphics pipeline.

The Fragment Shader looks like below.

```
layout (location = 0) out vec3 outDiffuse;
layout (location = 1) out vec3 outNormal;

void main()
{
    outDifuse = ...;
    outNormal = ...;
}
```

Can i do same thing in WebGL2?

I found glBlendFunci in OpenGL4 can specify draw buffer index, but not for WebGL2(ES3.0 I assume)

If WebGL2 doesn't provide functionality for this, I will just give up and implement it with limitation like just use first BlendFunc with warning log.